# Why I can not see results of routing in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

I have this code, and it is very good working on other environment without webpack.

This is **main.js** on frontend

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React from "react";
//import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./components/App.jsx";
import WizardIndex from "./components/index.js";
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App>
      <Route path="/signup" component={WizardIndex} />
    </App>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("mount-point")
);
```

This is **App.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="menu-bar">
          <div className="menu-item">
            <h3>App</h3>
            <Link to="/signup">Signup</Link>
          </div>
          <div className="content">{children}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And Here I include WizardIndex file **index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { Values } from "redux-form-website-template";
import store from "./store";
import showResults from "./showResults";
import WizardForm from "./WizardForm";
class WizardIndex extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>
   Hello!!!React Router
  </h1>
    );
  }
}

export default WizardIndex;
```

I see Signup link - button on the localhost:8050 But, Why
Why I can not see nothing after I press Signup button
I didnt have any error No in console webpack (there is all green ) Not in console of browser And when I reload the page localhost:8050/signup I get this note in browser but not in consol Cannot GET /signup

Comment: That's odd. Your code [works great for me](https://codesandbox.io/s/vq021q969l).

Comment: As far Cannot GET /signup on reload, I think that's an issue that could be solved using HashRouter